# framing in a header. Can I toenail from each side?

Tags: framing

i am doing a remodel and moved a 2-6 door over a few feet.  the original door has a 4x8 header, so I put in the same.   My understanding is the header should be affixed by 6 16d nails on each side. because the header was put up against existing framing, I can't shoot through the king stud into the header.  Can I toenail three nails per side, shooting through the header, into the king stud?

Comment: A sketch would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Yes, toenails will work. In some cases toenails hold better than nails run through the stud into the end grain. The nail head is what does a lot of the work, make sure the heads are set into the surface. It also helps the drywall set better, when you trim the door out you will find what I mean if you don't